# Pivot data in Stata or Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I need to use this data in Stata, but I don't know how to format it into the right shape.  It doesn't matter if I do it in Excel beforehand or after I transfer it to Stata.

My data is like

```
Country 2001 2002 2003
AFG     35    40   28
AGO     30    28   26
```

How do I change it to be

```
Country  Year  Press Freedom
AFG      2001    35
AFG      2002    40
AFG      2003    28
AGO      2001    30
AGO      2002    28
AGO      2003    26
```

Thanks

Comment: Use Power Query in Excel and unpivot... easy. Demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27671495/9245853).

Comment: In Stata this would be `reshape long`. The syntax would depend on the variable names for each year, as variable names can't start with numbers.